# How do I connect information to countries or locations on a map?

Tags: python, maps, methodology

Being a n00b would-be programmer, I want to create a simple memo program that allows the user to tie data (notes, etc.) to specific locations or countries on a map. Books like Head First Python didn't give me any clue and Google also doesn't provide easy hints how to proceed. 
I'm not primarily looking for specific programming hints (although that would be awesome), but more for a general methodology how we green beginners find the right tools and approaches to tackle such a project.

Comment: I would start to research and investigate what tools, technology's that exists. It is helpful to have knowledge foundation to start from, but not necessary.

If you don't want to create the tools by yourself. I would try to find existing librarys and the selection of programming language as result of target platform, existing tools.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Google is normally pretty good, just use the right keywords. I typed in python + geolocation and got this as the first hit, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geolocation-python/0.2.0. Is that enough to get you started? To learn programming, read blogs, watch videos, and try coding small examples in the console or IDE. Two most important things for the beginner when you program, from my own experience, is to know your input/output, i.e. what goes in what comes out - for a function, statement, expression - everything; and to know the type of the variable you are dealing with - string, list, object, etc. And, be audacious: everything is possible with programming - somebody has already solved the task you are dealing with, therefore, you can do it too.